# Definition of pointed Gromov-Hausdorff convergence for metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, metric-geometry, gromov-hausdorff-limit

Whereas the definition of Gromov-Hausdorff convergence for compact metric spaces seems to be standard, difference sources seem to give slightly different definitions of pointed Gromov-Hausdorff convergence for (noncompact) pointed metric spaces.

For example, *A course in metric geometry* (D. Burago, Yu. Burago, and S. Ivanov) at page 272 gives this definition

> **Definition A** A sequence $\{(X_n,d_n,p_n)\}$ of pointed metric spaces converges to the pointed metric space $\{(X,d,p)\}$ if for all $\varepsilon,r>0$ there exists a natural number $n_0$ such that for every $n>n_0$ there is a map $f:B(p_n,r)\rightarrow X$ such that
>
> 1. $f(p_n)=p$
> 2. $\text{dis} f<\varepsilon$ (i.e. $\sup_{B(p_n,r)}|d_n(x_1,x_2)-d(f(x_1),f(x_2))|<\varepsilon$)
> 3. the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $f(B(p_n,r))$ contains the ball $B(p,r-\varepsilon)$

On the other hand, Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry* (3rd edition) in Chapter 11.1.2 (page 401) restricts to [**proper** metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#P), introduces a pointed Gromov-Hausdorff distance as follows:
$$d_{\text{GH}}\left((X,p),(Y,q)\right)=\inf\{d_H(X,Y)+d(p,q)\}$$
where the inf is over all metrics $d$ on the disjoint union $X\sqcup Y$ which extend the metrics on $X$ and $Y$ and $d_H$ denotes the Hausdorff distance of $X$ and $Y$ as subsets of $X\sqcup Y$ and gives the following definition

> **Definition B** A sequence $\{(X_n,d_n,p_n)\}$ of pointed metric spaces converges to the pointed metric space $\{(X,d,p)\}$ if for all $r>0$ there exists a sequence $r_n\rightarrow r$ such that
> $$d_{\text{GH}}\left((\overline{B}(p_n,r_n),p_n),(\overline{B}(p,r),p)\right)\rightarrow 0$$

Finally, Gromov's own book *Metric Structures for Riemannian and Non-Riemannian Spaces* (Def. 3.1.4, at page 85) uses essentially the same definition as Petersen's, but restricts to (complete) locally compact [length metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric).

And these are not all the definitions I have found in the literature.
For example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09595v1) by Dorothea Jansen states (Definition 2.1)

> **Definition C** Let $(X, d_X , p)$ and $(X_n, d_{X_n} , p_n)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, be pointed proper
> metric spaces. If $$d_{\text{GH}}\left((\overline{B}(p_n,r),p_n),(\overline{B}(p,r),p)\right)\rightarrow 0$$ for all $r>0$ where the balls are equipped with the restricted metric, then $(X_n, p_n)$ converges to $(X, p)$ in the pointed Gromov-Hausdorff sense.

Not all of them are equivalent. For example, say $X_n$ is the space consisting of the two points $\{0,1+\frac{1}{n}\}$ and $X=\{0,1\}$ (both with the metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}$).
Here all $X_n$ (and $X$) are proper, but they are not length spaces. It is easy to see that $(X_n,0)\rightarrow (X,0)$ according to definitions A and B. However for all $n$, $\overline{B}_{X_n}(0,1)={0}$ and $\overline{B}_X(0,1)={0,1}$, so $(\overline{B}_{X_n}(0,1),0)\not\to (\overline{B}_X(0,1),0)$ and $(X_n,0)\not\to (X,0)$ according to definition C.

Also, [these notes](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Emarkmclean/MAT569-spring2020/convergencebeamer.pdf) (which adopt Petersen's definition B) claim that if $\{(X_n,d_n,p_n)\}$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) and $\{(X,d,p)\}$ are **compact** pointed spaces such that $d_{\text{GH}}\left((X_n,p_n),(X,p)\right)\to 0$, then $(X_n,p_n)\to (X,p)$ in the sense of definition B, i.e. for each $r>0$ there exist $r_n\to r$ such that $$d_{\text{GH}}\left((\overline{B}(p_n,r_n),p_n),(\overline{B}(p,r),p)\right)\rightarrow 0$$
without ever assuming the spaces are length spaces.

My questions are:

- When are these definitions equivalent?
- What are the advantages of restricting to proper spaces? What are the advantages of restricting to length spaces?
- Is there a reference which deals with these issues?